# How to pass props in vue from laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am new in vue. I am passing props from laravel to vue but got below error. Please guide me where i am wrong.

[image]

[image]

```
<jobs-component :countriesList="'{{$country_list}}'" :jobsRoute="'{{route('jobListing')}}'"></jobs-component>
```

```
export default {
    props: ["jobsroute", "countriesList"],
    components: {
        JobFilter
    },
    data() {
        return {
            jobs: [],
            axiosConfig: {
                headers: {
                    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
                }
            }
        };
    },
    created() {
        console.log(countriesList);
        this.fetchJobs();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchJobs() {
            axios.post(this.jobsroute).then(response => {
                this.jobs = response.data.data;
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: @tony19 if i remove country list variable then it works fine.

Comment: What is the value of `{{$country_list}}`?

Comment: @tony19 its array of objects, let me add a screenshot

Comment: Found the error thanks for your time

Comment: @RobinSingh Mind sharing what the error was?

Comment: @brombeer i have not converted object to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You could also return the object in Laravel's JSON response:

```
return response()->json(Country::get());
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#json-responses

Answer (score 0):

I found error myself

**Before**

```
 $country_list = Country::get();
```

**After**

```
 $country_list = Country::get()->toJson();
```